# i want to connect radio button method with selector statement in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, radio-button

```
let button8:ISRadioButton = ISRadioButton(frame: CGRect(x: 140, y: 75, width: 70, height: 35))

    button8.addTarget(self, action:#selector(buttonClicked4), for: .touchUpInside)

    button8.setTitle("Female", for: .normal)
    button8.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: .normal)
    button8.titleLabel?.font =  UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 12)

// method for radio button

@objc func buttonClicked4(_ isRadioButton:ISRadioButton){

    if isRadioButton.multipleSelectionEnabled{
        for radioButton in isRadioButton.otherButtons! {
            print("%@ is selected.\n", radioButton.titleLabel!.text ?? "");
        }
    }else{
        print("%@ is selected.\n", isRadioButton.titleLabel!.text ?? "");
    }


}
```

i want to connect radio button method with selector statement but through this code method is not executing

Comment: Small issue, probably not what is going on... you didn't post code where you've added the radio button to the view.  @Reinier_Melian, you may be onto something, but I'm trying to compare your code to what was posted - what's different?

Comment: use  `action:#selector(buttonClicked4(_:))` replace `button8.addTarget(self, action:#selector(buttonClicked4(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)` by `button8.addTarget(self, action:#selector(buttonClicked4(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)`

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing your code and then testing it for myself, I believe that the issue has to do with `addTarget` method. Your function includes `_ isRadioButton: ISRadioButton`, but when you add it to your target you use `buttonClicked4`. If you notice, there is nothing after this is declared. So you need to include `(_:)` after you declare your function in the `addTarget` method.

Your code should come out to the following:

```
let button8: ISRadioButton = ISRadioButton(frame: CGRect(x: 140, y: 75, width: 70, height: 35))

// Changed buttonClicked4 to buttonClicked4(_:)
button8.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonClicked4(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

button8.setTitle("Female", for: .normal)
button8.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: .normal)
button8.titleLabel?.font =  UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 12)

@objc func buttonClicked4(_ isRadioButton: ISRadioButton) {
    if isRadioButton.multipleSelectionEnabled {
        for radioButton in isRadioButton.otherButtons! {
            print("%@ is selected.\n", radioButton.titleLabel!.text ?? "")
        }
    } else {
        print("%@ is selected.\n", isRadioButton.titleLabel!.text ?? "")
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there an error that your getting, or is it just not running the function?